# DAE in Matlab: ode15s

Tags: dae

I have to solve this problem

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y''=4y'+\frac{1}{h}-7y\\ 
y(1)=1\\ 
y'(1)=1
\end{matrix}\right. \text{where} \; h=5y'-2y$$

as it were a DAE (I know I could just substitute $h$ into the equation, but this is just an example, because in reality the problem I have to solve is a DAE and more complex than this).
When I use `ode45` and treat the problem as a second order differential equation, the graph $t$ Vs. $y$ is

[image]

but when I treat it as a DAE, the graph is completely different and I do not understand why. Here is my code:

`ode45` second order differential equation

```
function yp = dae_normale(t,y)
yp = zeros(2,1);
yp(1) = y(2);
yp(2) = 4*y(2) + 1/(5*y(2) - 2*y(1) ) - 7*y(1);
```

`ode45` second order differential equation **run**

```
[t,y] = ode45('dae_normale',[1,5],[1,1]);
[t,y(:,1)]
plot(t,y(:,1))
```

DAE `ode15s`

```
function out = dae(t,y)
out = [y(2)
   4*y(2) + 1/y(3) - 7*y(1)
   y(3) - 5*y(2) + 2*y(1) ];
```

DAE `ode15s` **run**

```
y0 = [1; 1; 3];
M = [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 0];
options = odeset('Mass',M);
[t,y] = ode15s(@dae,[1 5],y0,options);
[t,y(:,1)]
plot(t,y(:,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ode45 is an explicit (Runge-Kutta) ODE solver and, therefore, is only conditionally
stable. Normally, ode45 will automatically reduce the step size to maintain
stability. But, as discussed in this article, [Error Control Matters](http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/vodef90web/ErrorControlMatters.pdf), sometimes it does not because the error tolerances are too large. Try modifying your code as follows to reduce the error tolerances:

```
opts=odeset('RelTol', 1e-4, 'AbsTol', 1e-7);
[t,y] = ode45('dae_normale',[1,5],[1,1], opts);
```